# How to hide "Anonymous (unverified)" in views?

Tags: views

I have a view that lists nodes created by the site users, therefore I have a column for usernames, that specific column looks like this:

```
+---------------------------+
| userA                     |
| userB                     |
| Anonymous (unverified)    |
| userC                     |
| userD                     |
| userE                     |
+---------------------------+
```

I want like to display an empty string for Anonymous users, just like this:

```
+-------+
| userA |
| userB |
|       |    <--- Empty text instead of "Anonymous (unverified)"
| userC |
| userD |
| userE |
+-------+
```

I know I can [modify the username](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_username_alter/7axw) "Anonymous" using a small custom module and hide "(unverified)" from the theme settings, but this is not what I'm looking for, I want Views not to display the username if the user is Anonymous.

Thank you.